# Find number of smaller values than the given value in BST

Tags: python, count, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find a number of smaller values than the given value x in a binary search tree (has n elements). I have written a recursive function. However, when I run it, it returns Nonetype. For example, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8 is contained in BST. I'm trying to get smaller values than 6 should be 3, but the output is None. Where is the problem with my code?

This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.data = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def addToNode(self, x):
        # root

        # add to left
        if (x < self.data):
            # empty -> 1
            if (self.left == None):
                p = Node(x)
                self.left = p
            else:
                # recursion
                self.left.addToNode(x)

        # add to right
        else:
            if (self.right == None):
                p = Node(x)
                self.right = p
            else:
                # recursion
                self.right.addToNode(x)

    def Nodesearchlower(self, x):
        if self.left and self.right:
            if (x > self.data):
                return 1 + self.right.Nodesearchlower(x) + self.left.Nodesearchlower(x)
            else:
                return 0 + self.left.Nodesearchlower(x)
        elif self.left:
            if (x > self.data):
                return 1 + self.left.Nodesearchlower(x)
            else:
                return 0 + self.left.Nodesearchlower(x)
        elif self.right:
            if (x > self.data):
                return 1 + self.right.Nodesearchlower(x)
            else:
                return 0 + self.right.Nodesearchlower(x)
        else:
            if (x > self.data):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addToBST(self, x):
        # empty -> 1
        if (self.root == None):
            p = Node(x)
            self.root = p
        # 1 => 2, 2 => 3, ...
        else:
            self.root.addToNode(x)

    def BSTsearchlower(self, x):
        self.root.Nodesearchlower(x)


# main
n, x = map(int, input().split())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
bst = BST()
for i in range(len(a)):
    bst.addToBST(a[i])
ans = bst.BSTsearchlower(x)
print(ans)
```

Comment: BSTsearchlower does not return the values from node search lower

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured the problem with my code: I missed "return" in the function BSTsearchlower(self, x) in the class BST.